# Frequent Hard Lockups

Tags: 20.04, keyboard, mouse, lockup

I have suddenly (in the past couple of days) begun experiencing hard lockups on my laptop. When this happens, neither the mouse, keyboard, or display respond. This seems to always happen when I am typing - the keystrokes I type don't appear on the screen until I move the mouse, then it rapidly catches up. Every dozen or so times this happens, the mouse won't move and the characters won't appear and I have to do a hard reset to recover.  Interestingly, if it hangs when I'm typing at the command prompt during the moment that I'm using auto-complete (tab) or if I try to backspace too far for the line, that little "dink" sound repeats over and over at about one second intervals until I reset the laptop. It happened even as I was entering this request.

I have run diagnostics and the memory, CPU, and disk drive all pass. This is a dual-boot laptop, and I haven't had this problem occur when running on the Windows side.  I have captured (via my phone camera) the last htop and syslog tail, but it's all greek to me.

Oh, and sometimes during bootup I get a new message on the screen (before the UI loads) that says something about one of the cores taking too long to do something, 28 seconds I think. I tried to capture a picture of that as well but it went away before I could get it in focus.

This is apparently an Ubuntu bug IMHO but I haven't a clue where to start looking for it. Can anyone help?

Details:

**Lenovo IdeaPad 3,
12G memory,
1TB disk (143G free),
Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS (all patches up to date),
Gnome 3.36.8, Graphics is Mesa Intel® UHD Graphics (ICL GT1)**

Gnome shell extensions:

```
$ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions
ls: cannot access '/home/david/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions': No such file or directory

$ ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions
total 68
drwxr-xr-x 17 root root 4096 Dec 16  2020 .
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root 4096 Jul  9 21:41 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Dec 16  2020 apps-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Dec 16  2020 auto-move-windows@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Aug 22 15:07 desktop-icons@csoriano
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Dec 16  2020 drive-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Dec 16  2020 horizontal-workspaces@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Dec 16  2020 launch-new-instance@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Dec 16  2020 native-window-placement@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Dec 16  2020 places-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Dec 16  2020 screenshot-window-sizer@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 May  9 15:57 ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Jul  9 21:41 ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Dec 16  2020 user-theme@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Dec 16  2020 window-list@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Dec 16  2020 windowsNavigator@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Dec 16  2020 workspace-indicator@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
```

[image: Crash snapshot]

[image: Another crash snapshot]

Comment: Ubuntu bug? I do not think so video issue probably. What have you changed upgraded installed or updated in the last week?

Comment: Please remove the images and paste it as plain text.

Comment: Do you have Nvidia? If so, what version driver? I see that you're running gnome-flashback and xorg. Try this and see if there's any change... go to the login screen, select your username, click on the icon in the lower-right corner of the screen, and select "Ubuntu under Wayland", then enter your password. Report back.

Comment: Also, edit your question and show me `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and `ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions`. Please use copy/paste text, and not screenshots. Thanks!

Comment: Try booting with your previous kernel version: https://askubuntu.com/q/82140/307523

Comment: --david: Well, I meant Ubuntu as opposed to hardware. I haven't changed or installed anything that I can remember except applying the updates when notified.

--Rinzwind:
 How do I get plain text from a frozen computer?

--heynnema:
 Best I can tell, I don't have Nvidia.  My graphics engine is Mesa Intel® UHD Graphics (ICL GT1). Question updated with gnome extensions.

--WinEunuuchs2Unix:
 I will try that.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix: It still hangs with the previous kernel.